# PHP Image Resize - Set Height & Width Auto

Tags: php, image, upload

Cant get image to resize with the following code.

Want to set a height of 300px and width of auto for all uploads.

Currently setting is to 100 x 100 just for testing purposes. This does nothing on the upload.

```js
// Escape user inputs for security

$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['id']);

$target_dir = "images/breweryimages/";
$size = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$base_file = rand(100000000000,10000000000000) . "-" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_file = $target_dir . $base_file;
$image = getimagesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']);
     $file_width=$image[0];
     $file_height=$image[1];
$file_width = 100;
$file_height = 100;
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 50000000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}


// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) . " " . $file_width . "has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would these values do anything to the file? You are not using them except for in your upload message.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will suit your needs

```
static public function square_crop($src_image, $dest_image, $dst_w = 100, $dst_h = 100, $jpg_quality = 90) {

    // Get dimensions of existing image
    $image = getimagesize($src_image);

    // Check for valid dimensions
    if( $image[0] <= 0 || $image[1] <= 0 ) return false;

    // Determine format from MIME-Type
    $image['format'] = strtolower(preg_replace('/^.*?\//', '', $image['mime']));

    // Import image
    switch( $image['format'] ) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $image_data = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_image);
        break;
        case 'png':
            $image_data = imagecreatefrompng($src_image);
        break;
        case 'gif':
            $image_data = imagecreatefromgif($src_image);
        break;
        default:
            // Unsupported format
            return false;
        break;
    }

    // Verify import
    if( $image_data == false ) return false;

    // Calculate measurements
    if( $image[0] & $image[1] ) {
        // For landscape images
        $x_offset = ($image[0] - $image[1]) / 2;
        $y_offset = 0;
        $square_size = $image[0] - ($x_offset * 2);
    } else {
        // For portrait and square images
        $x_offset = 0;
        $y_offset = ($image[1] - $image[0]) / 2;
        $square_size = $image[1] - ($y_offset * 2);
    }

    // Resize and crop
    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);
    if( imagecopyresampled(
        $canvas,
        $image_data,
        0,
        0,
        $x_offset,
        $y_offset,
        $dst_w,
        $dst_h,
        $square_size,
        $square_size
    )) {

        // Create thumbnail
        switch( strtolower(preg_replace('/^.*\./', '', $dest_image)) ) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                return imagejpeg($canvas, $dest_image, $jpg_quality);
            break;
            case 'png':
                return imagepng($canvas, $dest_image);
            break;
            case 'gif':
                return imagegif($canvas, $dest_image);
            break;
            default:
                // Unsupported format
                return false;
            break;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```